# Преобразование чисел из мантиссы с экспонентой

Tags: erlang

Получаю данные в виде {Exponenta, Mantissa} - {123,9135000000}, пробую получить число:

```
 12> D = 9135000000.
 9135000000
 13> D*math:pow(10, -5).
 91350.00000000001
```

В чем ошибка?

Comment: В приведенном коде ошибки нет. Что вы хотите в результате получить?

Comment: Очевидно это ошибка округления. Если Вы ещё не знаете, что в компьютере числа вовсе не такие, как хочется некоторым, то поищите литературку на тему представления чисел в компьютере.

Comment: Напишите ответ, чтобы вопрос был закрыт.

Comment: Сделал округление и все заработало